# How to get WiFi 6e (6GHz) to work on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking

I've read that WiFi 6e (6GHz) is only supported on Windows 11 because of location telemetry.

Is there a hack that can trick Windows 10 into allowing 6GHz connections?

Comment: "Regular" Wifi 6 (not 6e) runs on the 2.4 and 5Ghz frequency bands. These differences will usually require hardware designed to support these different frequencies. It looks as though WiFi 6e is a bridge standard getting things ready for WiFi 7 which supports all the WiFi 6 channels plus the 6Ghz frequencies. If your hardware only supports 6e it is unlikely that it will support 6 due to the frequency differences. So, first questions are: What frequencies does your COMPUTER hardware support, and what frequencies does your WIRELESS ROUTER broadcast?

Comment: You are correct. Both WiFi 7 and WiFi 6e do not support Windows 10 at the 6 GHz frequency band. You will be able to connect to your 5 GHz access points with WiFi 6e hardware but you will be unable to use the 6 Ghz frequency band on Windows 10.  The good news your hardware likely supports Windows 11 either officially or unofficially.

Answer (score 1):

From [Linus Tech Tips](https://linustechtips.com/topic/1501650-is-there-a-way-to-enable-6e-on-win10-without-shelling-out-5-for-a-sketchy-3rd-party-ax210-driver/): "[T]he reason why it requires windows 11, is because of regulatory requirements. the module will *not* enable 6e [ed.] unless location data can confirm it is in a region that allows civilian broadcast on 6Ghz... and apparently windows 10 can't do this."

However, there is a simple, free, work-around, if you do not want to or cannot update to Windows 11: Use **Ubuntu 22.04**, which *does* support 6e:

- See [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1460453/wifi-6e-ubuntu-20-04-not-able-to-connect).
- See [Superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/1759511/why-is-the-6-ghz-band-not-working-with-my-wi-fi-6-card)

There is no need to install anything - make a [persistent](https://www.linuxuprising.com/2019/08/rufus-creating-persistent-storage-live.html) Ubuntu 22.04 Live USB and boot from that to test. Why *persistent*? Because that enables installing additional drivers that might be needed. If it works, just install to the main drive, alongside Windows or stand-alone (likely it would not work with 6e in Windows System for Linux, WSL, though).

### Caveats:

- Use a fast USB drive, and be aware that a persistent OS running from flash USB is still *s l o w*.
- WiFi 6e is enabled only [in specific countries](https://www.wi-fi.org/countries-enabling-wi-fi-in-6-ghz-wi-fi-6e). If it is *not* allowed in your locale, the system will "fink' on you and disable it.

Comment: Thanks. The only things I've seen indicated that Ubuntu did not support 6e. One of my devices is primarily a Plex Server, so I'd actually prefer to run Ubuntu instead of Windows. Plex uses a lot of local bandwidth on my internal network, so my goal would be to move that off the 2.4 GHz and 5 GHz and save those for the devices that only support them.

Comment: The regulatory requirement is on the hardware manufacturers, not the end users. (And I know that 6GHz is allowed locally because my phone has it.) So there should be some way to spoof the location data so that the 6e adapter knows to enable 6GHz.